# Help with formatting a predesigned resume template (changing the margins)

Tags: spacing, formatting, resume, cv

I have this resume template that I got from a friend who found it online on GitHub (I don't know where exactly): [resume.cls](https://ufile.io/y3w2z) and [main.tex](https://ufile.io/3gpr4). I am very new to Latex so can someone help me align things so it looks like this: [PDF File](https://ufile.io/gs8n1) or [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLikm.png) (the black line is only to show alignment, I don't actually want that). I have no idea what corresponds to what in the cls. I tried experimenting with hspace{} in the tex but it did not work. I want the bullets to still be indented as it was before.

Edit: Information that helps narrow down the problem. If you go to line 439 in the cls file it says there are two types of section headings:

`% 1) the section heading is all on one line and directly
%    below it, is the body of the text
% 2) the section heading is entirely in the left margin
%    (possibly taking multiple lines) with the body of
%    the text next to it`

My current format is 2), and I want to switch to the other one, 1).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Templates are usually a bad idea because they too often come to you cluttered beyond all comprehension.  If you're only wanting to adjust margins, then look to the geometry package.  If there are other changes, create a minimal working example and ask us how to help you make those changes.  Unfortunately for you, posting only a template class and an desired image won't get too much of a response, in part because it's not clear if you still want the resume aspect of the template, or just the margins.

Comment: @teepeemm I have no idea on how to go about solving this. I just started using Latex like 5 days ago. I don't know how to use any packages. I have just made my resume by updating the words. I thought that a simple number change in the .cls would help because all we're doing is shifting to the sections left and under so it's aligned but I don't know how to do this because I have no idea how to read a .cls file. If you compile the original files and compare to the pdf/image it's clear what I want when looking at before and after.

Comment: Since your friend asked this question and got the best answers available 10 years ago I will refer you back to https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1839

Comment: Just to be clear what you asked is how to change \documentclass[margin,line]{resume} to \documentclass[overlapped,line]{resume} without understanding that its not a good way to learn how to edit LaTeX

Comment: @KJO really appreciate you taking the time to respond and try to help though! I'll learn Latex when I need it for more than resume, but not yet

Comment: @KJO I figured out how to solve my problem by editing the class files. I got it by trial and error and changing numbers around to experiment. Check out the answer below

Comment: Glad you were able to answer your own question, your efforts may inspire others to do likewise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem I had by making modifications to the class file. You can [download the new class file and the tex file here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LAOAqvCwECH3rnNxJmMuyMv-gB_qjx5y?usp=sharing) if you want to compare the changes. Most the changes were made in after line 819 in the class file.

Answer (score 1):

Since your template is about 20 years old and not easy to modify without resorting to editing the class file.

I would look for a simpler more up-to date variant e.g. [CV-US on this page](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume)

*OLD stylistic template (set overlapped*)    **Modern CV-US**

[image: OLD stylistic template]  [image: Modern CV-US]

If you really want horizontal rules and bullet points you could look at the first template for clues, however you should acquaint yourself with how to create and add them from a  recent TeX primer.